# C# Generic factory pattern for n-derived objects (create all super-types)?

Tags: c#

I have a generic object factory `FactoryBase<T>` with a factory method:

```
public abstract class FactoryBase<T> where T : new()
{
    public virtual T CreateInstance()
    {
        T thing = new T();

        // Tweak 'thing' a bit...

        return thing;
    }
}
```

This works great for creating concrete factories for various types:

```
public class FruitFactory : FactoryBase<Fruit>
{
    public override Fruit CreateInstance()
    {
        Fruit fruit = base.CreateInstance();

        // Do some Fruit polishing stuff...

        return fruit;
    }
}
```

However, the pattern breaks down if I want to create a factory type derived from `Fruit`:

**First attempt: (WORKS, but INCORRECT)**

Here, `AppleFactory` directly inherits `FactoryBase<Apple>` -- this is wrong because `AppleFactory` should rely upon `FruitFactory` to build a nice polished `Fruit` upon which to build our `Apple`:

```
// Should inherit FruitFactory, not FactoryBase
public class AppleFactory : FactoryBase<Apple>
{
    public override Apple CreateInstance()
    {
        Apple apple = base.CreateInstance();

        // FruitFactory is left out above, so...
        // ...we have to do all the Fruit polishing stuff...
        // ... and any apple stuff...

        return apple;
    }
}
```

**Second attempt: (Complete fail)**

Inheriting `FruitFactory` is clearly an error because it is non-generic and returns a `Fruit` not an `Apple`:

```
// COMPILE ERRORS
public class AppleFactory : FruitFactory
{
    public override Apple CreateInstance()  // ERROR: Override method must return Fruit
    {
        Apple apple = base.CreateInstance(); // ERROR: FruitFactory returns a Fruit
        return apple;
    }
}
```

### The "Ugly" Solution?

By refactoring `FruitFactory` into a generic`FruitFactory<T>` I can create a properly derived `AppleFactory`:

```
public abstract class FruitFactory<T> where T : Fruit, new()
{
    public override T CreateInstance()
    {
        T fruit = (T)base.CreateInstance();

        // Do some Fruit polishing stuff...

        return fruit;
    }
}

// AppleFactory that property calls FruitFactory<Apple>
public class AppleFactory : FruitFactory<Apple>
{
    public override Apple CreateInstance()
    {
        Apple apple = base.CreateInstance();

        // ... ONLY apple stuff needed!!!

        return apple;
    }
}
```

I purposely make `FruitFactory<T>` abstract because it seems ugly and redundant for client code to call upon a a `FruitFactory<Fruit>`. Thus, I provide a non-generic `FruitFactory` which needs no body to be fully functional:

```
// Concrete FruitFactory
public class FruitFactory : FruitFactory<Fruit> { }
```

### Complaints:

Each time I need a factory for a more-derived type I have to convert the corresponding base type's factory to an abstract generic.

In other words, if I have a `FooFactory` I have to convert it to a `FooFactory<T>` in order to create `DerivedFooFactory : FooFactory<DerivedFoo>`

Simultaneously, I must make a new concrete `FooFactory : FooFactory<Foo>`.

Or... I could the generic factories directly:

```
var fruitFactory = new FruitFactory<Fruit>(); // Double-Fruity! sigh...
```

Is there a cleaner way to create an `AppleFactory` that first gets an `Apple` out of a `FruitFactory` without needing generic classes for each 'middle-man' type in the inheritance chain?

Note: I really don't want to use reflection or complex schemes.

Comment: It's really not clear what's going on here - particular the "AppleFactory directly inherits FactoryBase<Apple> instead of going through FruitFactory to first get a Fruit which is in the inheritance chain for Apple" - what do you mean? How is `AppleFactory` meant to know about `FruitFactory`? If it creates an `Apple`, in what way is that not creating a `Fruit`? If you could give a more complete example of what's going wrong when you try that, it would help...

Comment: Of course an `Apple` is a `Fruit`... what I mean to communicate is `AppleFactory` should utilize `FruitFactory` to get an apple with all the 'fruit polishing' done instead of going straight to `FactoryBase` for a raw apple. THE QUESTION IS TRULY: Looking for a clean pattern to build a factory that follows this base type build order.

Comment: So do you want an AppleFactory class or not? In some statements you're complaining that you need an AppleFactory at all, and in others you're saying that you want AppleFactory to use FruitFactory. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still having trouble following your question, but I *think* it would be solved by making `FruitFactory<T>` non-abstract:

```
public class FruitFactory<T> : FactoryBase<T> where T : Fruit, new()
{        
    // I'm assuming this is in FactoryBase<T>
    public override T CreateInstance()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Then you can derive from that and override `CreateInstance` when you write `AppleFactory`.

Comment: **`FruitFactory<T>` is intentionally abstract.** The non-generic `FruitFactory` implements the abstract `FruitFactory<Fruit>` to hide that little bit of silly redundancy. I don't wish to have an `AppleFactory<Apple>` and `CarFactory<Car>` -- THAT is what I'm looking for a better solution to and is why I posted originally.

Comment: @Kevin: It's still completely unclear what you want. If you want `FruitFactory<T>` to be abstract, I don't see how you can complain when you have to create a derived class... that's what making it abstract is doing.

Comment: I hope my coding is better than my communication. :) What I'm hoping for is non-redundant syntax. Either `new AppleFactory()` or `new Factory<Apple>()` would be great. But if `AppleFactory` derives from `FruitFactory<Apple>` I must use `FruitFactory<Fruit>` to get a Fruit (redundant), or create a shadow `FruitFactory` to hide that same fact. I'm looking for a factory pattern that follows the inheritance chain for the type being built and calls each super-class factory in order (similar to constructors). Actually, I have that but I'm unhappy with syntax. Suggestions? Thanks 4 ur patience.

Comment: Alternatively, I could simply concede to have `AppleFactory` construct a new apple with `Apple apple = new Apple()` then directly call `FruitFactory.Initialize(Fruit apple)`. By baking-in knowledge of the base type (instead of relying on generic inheritance) I would end up with a clean `new AppleFactory()` and `new FruitFactory()`.

Comment: @Kevin: I could have sworn I replied to this earlier, but I can't see it now... I'm confused as to what just plain `FruitFactory` would do. `Fruit` sounds like an abstract class to me - do you have a hierarchy with lots of concrete base classes? I usually find that only leaf classes are concrete. If `Fruit` is abstract, then a non-generic `FruitFactory` doesn't make much sense to start with.

Comment: Yes! Lots of leafs are also concrete bases! Specifically, I have an air pollution measurement (`Fruit`) and a pollution forecast (`Apple`). A forecast is-a measurement that adds a prediction date. Both are concrete "leaf" classes. `FruitFactory` exists as a leaf for `FruitFactory<Fruit>`. Each concrete leaf is decorated with an attribute such that when I need a `Fruit` I find the factory decorated with `[TypeFactory(typeof(Fruit))]` (which is pre-registered into a `Dictionary<Type,Type>`). Creating empty concrete leaf classes smells, perhaps it is proper and I am chasing my tail?

Comment: @Kevin: Why would you have an *empty* concrete leaf class? Why doesn't it need to do anything specific to that type? Just how many types do you have like this anyway?

Comment: IDEA! Essentially, I have built a "tree" of generic factories that mirror my concrete inheritance chain. I dislike the smell of manually having to add empty leaf classes where I need a concrete. Suppose, instead, I decorate the generic `FruitFactory<T>` with the attribute `[TypeFactory(typeof(Fruit))]` -- thus my code knows to get a `Fruit` it needs to insert `Fruit` as the generic argument to get a `FruitFactory<Fruit>` and I don't need all the empty leaf classes! That seems a good "solution" to me.

Comment: Around a dozen empty leafs if I built-out this pattern. Their purpose is only to create a concrete from the generic (i.e., the empty leaf `FruitFactory` inherits the generic `FruitFactory<Fruit>` which cannot be instantiated as `FruitFactory<T>`). When you ask "why would you"--that is the essence of what smells to me. Proposed solution above?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a similar problem, we have a inheritance hierarchy that uses constructors with parameters AND needs "polishing" on creation.
The problem was that we are unable to reuse the "polishing" code of the less derived factory, because it was coupled with the "new" statement (Which is not a parameterless constructor).

I think the solution we found might be useful for other that get on this question because of similar problems (but it still has the generics redundancy):

```
// Abstract factory class that handles the method calls
public abstract class AbstractFactory<TDto, TObject> : IFactory<TDto, TObject>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create and initialize the object using data from Dto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public TObject Create(TDto dto)
    {
        TObject obj = CreateInstance(dto);
        Initialize(dto, obj);
        return obj;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new instance of the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract TObject CreateInstance(TDto dto);

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the instance of the object (the "polishing")
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"></param>
    /// <param name="objeto"></param>
    protected abstract void Initialize(TDto dto, TObject objeto);
}

// The Fruit is abstract, so is the factory. It don't override the abstract method that will have the "new" statement, just the "polishing" stuff.
public abstract class FruitFactory<TFuitDto, TFruit> : AbstractFactory<TFruitDto, TFruit>
    where TFruitDto : FruitDto
    where TFruit : Fruit
{
    protected override void Initialize(TFruitDto dto, TFruit objeto)
    {
       // Do the fruit "polishing" here
    }
}

public class AppleFactory<TAppleDto, TApple> : AbstractFactory<TAppleDto, TApple>
    where TAppleDto : AppleDto
    where TApple : Apple
{
    protected override TApple CreateInstance(TAppleDto dto)
    {
       // Create a new Apple and don't do any "polishing" here (will break reusability)
       return new Apple(dto) as TApple
    }

    protected override void Initialize(TFruitDto dto, TFruit objeto)
    {
       // Do the Apple "polishing" here
       // Call the Fruit "polish"
       base.Initialize(dto, objeto);
    }
}
```

If there is need to create another derived class (like BigApple and SmallApple), just do another factory and don't call base.CreateInstance(dto) inside the most derived CreateInstance, that way the "new" is executed only for the most derived class, and the polishing go cascading all the way up.

There is some redundancy in the where clauses, but it is encapsulated by the DI, so I think it is Ok.