# How to Implement a Static Method in an Abstract Class that Creates Concreate Child Classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, static-methods, factory-pattern

I have one abstract parent class with a static method that creates needed child class using ID value

```
public abstract class AbstractParent
{
    abstract public int ID { get; }

    // Other common properties

    public static AbstractParent CreateConcreteClassUsingID(int id)
    {
        // Create correct child class using ID
    }
}
```

Two child classes derived from this abstract class

Class A

```
public class ChildClassA : AbstractParent
{
    public override int ID => 1;
}
```

Class B

```
public class ChildClassB : AbstractParent
{
    public override int ID => 2;
}
```

**What I'm Trying to Achieve**

I'm trying to create a static function that takes an ID as a parameter and creates the correct child class using that parameter.

**Solutions**

Here is the naive approach that I've come up with at first

```
public static AbstractParent CreateConcreteClassUsingID(int id)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            return new ChildClassA();
        }
        else if (id == 2)
        {
            return new ChildClassB();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("ID is invalid");
        }
    }
```

This solution is bad because if I add a new child class that implements parent class or if I change ID value of a child class I need to change this function also.

**What I Tried**

I've searched on Google and found out that *Factory Pattern* might be related to this problem. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878216/factory-pattern-without-a-switch-or-if-then) question on StackOverflow. But I couldn't comprehend and implement that solution in my situation.

I've come up with a solution using reflection:

```
public static AbstractParent CreateConcreteClassUsingID(int id)
    {
        List<AbstractParent> allChildClassInstances = GetAllChildClassInstances();

        AbstractParent correctChild = allChildClassInstances.Find(c => c.ID == id);

        if (correctChild == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("ID is invalid");
        }

        return correctChild;
    }

    private static List<AbstractParent> GetAllChildClassInstances()
    {
        List<AbstractParent> allChildClassInstances = new List<AbstractParent>();

        foreach (Type type in ChildClassTypes)
        {
            AbstractParent childInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as AbstractParent;
            allChildClassInstances.Add(childInstance);
        }

        return allChildClassInstances;
    }

    public static List<Type> ChildClassTypes
    {
        get
        {
            if (childClassTypes == null)
            {
                childClassTypes = new List<Type>();

                foreach (var domain_assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                {
                    var assembly_types = domain_assembly.GetTypes()
                      .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractParent)) && !type.IsAbstract);

                    childClassTypes.AddRange(assembly_types);
                }

            }
            return childClassTypes;
        }
    }

    private static List<Type> childClassTypes = null;
```

This solves my problem but I'm searching for a better and shorter solution if possible.

My questions are:

1. Is there a well-defined solution for creating concrete child classes in run-time?
2. How can I implement (or should I implement) Factory Pattern in this situation such that I don't need to change anything when I add a new child class or when I change ID value of a child class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't read the code or looked for duplicates, but from the title why not use generics or a standard factory pattern with activator and reflexion?

Comment: @OlivierRogier I've come up with a solution using reflection but I'm searching for a better solution. I've tried Factory Pattern but I couldn't eliminate if cases in the method. Can you share your solution using Factory Pattern?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Generic factory pattern for n-derived objects (create all super-types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805674/c-sharp-generic-factory-pattern-for-n-derived-objects-create-all-super-types) and [Factory design pattern; parent = new child()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149537/) and [Implement Factory pattern using Generics once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103768/) and [Generic factory method to return specific object based on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391622/)

Comment: You could also use a custom attribute to decorate your child classes. Provide the attribute with a constructor taking the id. In a static constructor you can then scan the assembly (or even more assemblies then the current) for classes decorated with this attribute. Store the types in a hashmap (int, type) and you can use the hashmap to look them up and create instances

Comment: @OlivierRogier All these answers provide solutions using if/switch statements or using real types (like var admin = pf.getPerson("admin"); ) instead of some other parameter. So these are not the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: @Sascha In that case I need to use reflection, right?

Comment: @AliIhsanElmas Where do you see in the suggested duplicates that generic factory pattern need if/switch? On the contrary, there is no need for activator nor to test the requested type! See also [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Correct me if I'm wrong but in that example, you need to know which class you want to create beforehand.  If you read my question you can see that I'm trying to create a function that decides which concrete class to create using an abstract attribute. the same goes for the link you provided. Example:var productA = factory.CreateProductA();

Comment: Using generics, no. [Generics Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm) • [Generics level 2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics) • [Generics in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/) • [Generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: Yes, this is reflection based. But as you would do this only initially and save all implementing you're in a dictionary, the performance impact is usually neglect able.